# How to change the color of a button when i clicked another button?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to do is when i click the btn1 (will enable the combobox ), i will choose a color(ex. red) in the combobox and then click the btnSave. The color of btn1 will change into Red (Permanently).

Comment: Show us your code attempt.  Also include the tag for c# or vb.net, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i assume using vb

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("no", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("color", GetType(String))
    dt.Rows.Add("1", "Red")
    dt.Rows.Add("2", "Blue")

    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = dt.Columns("color").ToString
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = dt.Columns("no").ToString
    ComboBox1.Enabled = False
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ComboBox1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ComboBox1.Enabled <> False Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.FromName(ComboBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

CMIIW